# How to add link tags in a custom document in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I want to add these fonts to the head:

```
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

The only problem is, I have no idea where to place those tags.
This is my _document.tsx:

```
import Document, { DocumentContext } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

try {
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: (
      <>
        {initialProps.styles}
        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
      </>
    ),
  };
} finally {
  sheet.seal();
}

 }
  }
```

Where can i add those link tags in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
 static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
try {
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: (
      <>
        {initialProps.styles}
        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
      </>
    ),
    head: [
      <link key="1" rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />,
      <link
        key="2"
        rel="preconnect"
        href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
        crossOrigin="true"
      />,
      <link
        key="3"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />,
    ],
  };
} finally {
  sheet.seal();
}
  }
}
```

You can add the head property with an array of HTML tags.
Also you have to add the key element!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `render()` function.

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    // your getInitialProps implementation here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          // put your link here
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></link>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

You can check next.js doc for more information:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document